# How do I extract specific values from the JSON response in Postman using a test?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I need to be able to parse through the JSON results from a Postman response to just pull out the **name** value in the console output. My JSON looks like this:

```
"total_count": 7,
"entries": [
    {
        "type": "collaboration",
        "id": "21829111111",
        "created_by": null,
        "created_at": "2020-03-24T05:37:09-07:00",
        "modified_at": "2020-03-24T05:37:09-07:00",
        "expires_at": null,
        "status": "accepted",
        "accessible_by": {
            "type": "group",
            "id": "3085402",
            "name": "Test",
            "group_type": "managed_group"
```

Most of the examples I find are using extracted value to create a variable but I really just need a simple list I can copy and paste.

I've used this code to do something similar but I am not sure how to modify it for us with this data:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var usernames = response.map(function(account){
    return account.credentials.userName;
});
console.log(usernames);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through it:

```js
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
```

[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is taking the JSON response in as a string, and converting it to a JS object, which will then be stored in `response`.

```js
response.map(...)
```

The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is called on an array and takes a function as a parameter. It calls the function you provide it once for each element in the array that it's called on.

For your particular case, we'll need to modify this a little, since `response` is an object, rather than an array, and the value you're after, `name`, is nested in the `entries` array inside of `response`. To account for this, we're going to call `map()` directly on the nested array, and set it equal to a new variable to store the result, like this:

```js
var names = response.entries.map(...);
```

Now, we can pass `map()` a function that will extract the name from each element in the entries array. Our function needs to accept the array element as a parameter, and return the extracted name so that `map()` can add it to the new array it's making.

```js
function(entry) {
  return entry.accessible_by.name;
}
```

In the end, we end up with this:

```js
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var names = response.entries.map(function(entry) {
  return entry.accessible_by.name;
});

console.log(names);
```

This will output an array of names to your browser console. `["Test", ...]`

Bonus:
With a little JavaScript syntactic sugar (specifically [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), we can make the function code a little cleaner:

```js
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var names = reponse.entries.map(entry => entry.accessible_by.name);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaining things in detail! This worked perfectly and now I understand the syntax and was able to modify it for other similar data.