# How to extract specific values from JSON response in Postman and concatenate

Tags: arrays, json, postman

I need to be able to do the following in Postman

1. Parse through a JSON response
2. Retrieve specific values: some nested, some not
3. (optional) Concatenate the final result

I can currently perform 1 and I can accomplish 2 for one specific value with the help of this explanation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63287130/how-do-i-extract-specific-values-from-the-json-response-in-postman-using-a-test)

What I can't do is retrieve two values. Below is the sample response I am working with

```
{
    "part": "9FH74T00",
    "summaries": [
        {
            "id": "A1AGQF32TR"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was able to modify the JS from the link above to extract the nested `id` value

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var ids = response.summaries.map(function(summary) {
  return summary.id;
});
console.log(ids);
```

How can I expand on the JS to also retrieve the `part` value and ideally output that in the console as `part = id` or `9FH74T00 = A1AGQF32TR`

Comment: what about `console.log(response.part + "=" + ids);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lucas-nguyen's seems a valid response/comment to what you propose. What is not well explained is the model. `summaries` is an array so would you get multiple ids? The fact that you use a `map` makes me thing there will be multiple ids.

```js
part = id1,id2,id3
```

or

```js
part = id1
part = id2
part = id3
```

I've [created a sample request](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/request/19391207-27e9d9ee-9581-4d25-82da-96e181a75752) with your payload and two ids in `summaries`. I've `console.log` 3 approaches:

1. single part and single id
2. single part and ids in a list
3. single part and ids in tuples

So with the example response:

```json
{
"part": "9FH74T00",
"summaries": [
      {
        "id": "A1AGQF32TR"
      },
      {
        "id": "SECONDID"
      }
    ]
}
```

You would get the following output:

```
 Option 1:
 
9FH74T00 = A1AGQF32TR
 

Option 2, list of ids:
 
9FH74T00 = A1AGQF32TR,SECONDID
 

Option 3, list of ids:
 
9FH74T00 = A1AGQF32TR
 
9FH74T00 = SECONDID
```

If for some reason you can't [open the example](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/request/19391207-27e9d9ee-9581-4d25-82da-96e181a75752), this is my test tab:

```js
const response = pm.response.json().data;

// Just concatenate single part and single id
console.log("\nOption 1:")
console.log(`${response.part} = ${response.summaries[0].id}`)

// Co
console.log("\nOption 2, list of ids:")
const ids = response.summaries.map( x => x.id)
console.log(`${response.part} = ${ids.join(",")}`)

console.log("\nOption 3, list of ids:")
ids.forEach( x => console.log(`${response.part} = ${x}`))
```

Comment: this was very helpful. I am new to Postman and JS and I was not aware at first that map() is an iterator and so I assumed I would also need that to grab the 'sku'. Your explanation made perfect sense, and yes, I have multiple 'id' in my response body.